# Работа с файловой системой в Java

Tags: java, файлы

Копирую файл из одной директории в другую. `sourceFile = new File(e:\temp\temp.txt"), destFile = new File(e:\temp2\temp3\temp.txt")`, папок temp2 и temp3 нет. Предполагается, что данный путь создается строкой `destFile.createNewFile();`.

```
public void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if(!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    finally {
        if(source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if(destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
}
```

При попытке скопировать файл в несуществующую директорию ловлю `FileNotFoundExeption`, хотя проверяю путь `destFile.exists()` и в случае, если пути не существует, создаю его `destFile.createNewFile()`.

Еще наблюдения: наличие целевой директории также не означает успех, необходимо в ее свойствах сначала убрать галочку "Только для чтения". Я так понимаю, это проблема доступа...

Как разрешить создание директории? Куда смотреть, куда копать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сначала создать директорию, а потом уже в ней файл. Для это есть метод

> mkdirs()

```
//определяем директорию
destFile = new File("e:\\temp2\\temp3\\");
//создаём все несуществующие
destFile.mkdirs();
//теперь создаём сам файл
destFile = new File("e:\\temp2\\temp3\\temp.txt");
destFile.createNewFile();
```